# laravel @include with @section in <head>

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've a simple main layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    @yield('style')
</head>

<body>
@include('layouts.frontend.partials.slider')
@yield('javascript')
</body>
</html>
```

**layouts.frontend.partials.slider**

```
@section('style')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
@append

@section('javascript')
<script></script>
@append

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="1000">Slide 1</div>

        <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="1000">Slide 2</div>

        <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="1000">Slide 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="swiper-button-prev">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="swiper-button-next">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The `@section('style')` will be ignored while the `@section('javascript')` is working fine within the include file...
I've reduced both files (main and include) to a minimum and swapped the position of style and javascript without any difference

What seems to be working is to change to position from the `@yield('style')` to the body, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>

</head>

<body>
@include('layouts.frontend.partials.slider')
@yield('javascript')
@yield('style')
</body>
```

Maybe it's not allowed to have `@section` in an include file?

What i want to archive is to have multiple partial includes with it's own css and javascript includes

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to do, it's good because you have some flexibility.

You create a master template, put your main files

**master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

    @section('css')
        <!-- some master css here -->
    @show

</head>
<body>
    @section('navbar')
        @include('common.navbar')
    @show

    @yield('content')        

    @include('common.footer')

    @section('js')
        <!-- some js here -->
    @show   
</body>
</html>
```

The others childs extends the master, you'll have all your layout and can customize what you want:

**Child blade**

```
@extends('master')

@section('css')
    @parent
    <!-- more css -->
@endsection

@section('navbar')
    @parent
@endsection

@section('content')

<!-- Main content goes here -->

@endsection

@section('js')
    <!-- replace js and add my own -->
    <!-- others js -->
@endsection
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... however, i know how to create a master and child blade. what i want to know is if it is possible to have sections within an included file. i want to add e.g 10 partial blade files in my master or child blade file to have e.g the navbar, slider, contact form... within small partial files and not directly in my master or child blade

Answer (score 0):

Did you try extending your child blade file to use the master template?

At the top of `layouts.frontend.partials.slider` did you put `@extends('layout.master')` (or whatever the path to your master template is?)

It could be an issue caused by the order in which you are including files. Wouldn't a simpler solution be to have a `@yield('slider')` in your master template and simply wrap the slider content in `@section('slider')` and drop the `@include...`?